# I cannot load the PPCG meta

Tags: support, per-site-meta, error-message

When I try to go to https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/, I get an error just like this:

> [image]

I'm not sure what the problem is and i'm pretty sure this is a bug

This has been happening since last week, when I first tried.

Comment: Not reproduced: Windows 7 Ent x64, behind corporate firewall, Chrome Version 69.0.3497.81

Comment: @JeffZeitlin It isn't happening with a few people I've talked to about it, it only seems to be happening for me

Comment: Then I'd check local-to-you things, like dumping cookies and history in your browser, turning off adblockers, et cetera.

Comment: obvious questions: does it happen on all browsers? does it still happen if you log out?

Comment: Which also puts this issue squarely into [su] territory.

Comment: @dzaima I don't have access to other browsers, and im trying again after relogging

Answer (score 3):

This problem was fixed when I logged out and back in.